# Jquery click not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, wordpress

I have a wordpress site.

I add custom thumbnails in product section, it shows vertically. I just add the jquery code following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.active-thumb-link a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     var imgSrc = $(this).attr('href');
     var imgFind = $(".flickity-slider > div > a ").each(function(){ 
                   if($(this).attr('href') == imgSrc){
                       $(this).closest('div').css({"position": "absolute", "left": "0%"});  
                    } 

             });

});
```

Code Motive: When user click on thumbnail image =, this fucntion get the "href" attribute of the clicked image. This "href" and image src is same that i want to display in product image div. i also add some css in jquery code for display the image. Everything is working fine.

Issue is: Suppose 4 thumbnails appearing as ascending order like"

**THUNMB1** 
**THUNMB2** 
**THUNMB3** 
**THUNMB4**

When i click first time thumb1,thumb2,thumb3,thumb4 it works, 
But when click like this order

```
1.) Click thumb1 works good
2.) Click thumb2 works good
3.) Click thumb3 works good
4.) **Click thumb2 Not works after that nothing works when i click on previously clicked thumbnail again. This is the main issue**
```

Thanks! Plz help me

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle.net with a failing example?

Comment: This code is added in wordpress website In which they generates an html dynamically

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you need to provide a failing example if someone is going to help you.

Comment: Use your browser's inspector to copy the relevant HTML snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the images that are not being clicked back to their normal position. Inside your if-statement you could set all images to whatever first position they initially have, and then change the position of the closest one, like your already doing.